# LayoutTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID UserName for the username

Tags: vb.net

im making a website and ive never used visual studio 2012 before and having difficulty fixing the errors that are appearing, does anyone know what this error is about?

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/821x409q90/661/407a87.png

```
   <asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
            </p>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" Width="266px" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="Please enter your username." />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" Width="263px" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="Please enter your password." />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="checkbox">Remember me?</asp:Label>
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log in" />
            </fieldset>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
```

Comment: is that the code for my login page?

Comment: Cant fit in the whole code so will post in 2 parts

Comment: The error says the LayoutTemplate is missing a text box with the ID "Password", but the code you posted seems to be OK: it works for me.